# How to add an image while we drag n drop tree item?

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop

I have a tree with number of childs and i want to drag and drop these child items on a vertical panel. Right now its working fine.The only thing i want to know is can we add an image in the place of small icon which comes at the time of dragNdrop.

Comment: What kind of drag and drop? Native? gwt-dnd? Something else?

Comment: gwt-dnd -PickupDragController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the [`newDragProxy()`](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/source/browse/DragDrop/src/com/allen_sauer/gwt/dnd/client/PickupDragController.java#352) method of the `PickupDragController` in order to provide your own proxy widget (say, an image) when the drag starts.

Do note that you also need to use `setBehaviorDragProxy(true)` to allow dragging proxies instead of the original widgets (i.e., the original widgets will stay in place, and you simply drag a proxy of it, that you can style as you wish).